# Parametrize test classes inherited from same base

Tags: python, pytest

I have generic base test class that is shared between my tests. I would like to parametrize some of my tests, but looks like decorator `@pytest.mark.parametrize` is applied to `Base` class and I receive `ValueError: duplicate 'params'` error. Is there a way to do what I want? I don't want to apply parameters for individual functions, as there are a lot of them in classes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pytest


class Base(object):
    def test_example(self, something):
        assert something


@pytest.mark.parametrize("params", [1])
class TestBar(Base):
    @pytest.fixture()
    def something(self, params):
        return params * params


@pytest.mark.parametrize("params", [1, 2])
class TestBar1(Base):
    @pytest.fixture()
    def something(self, params):
        return params + params
```

Comment: Why do you need a base class like that at all?

Comment: I'm writing a rest client for some application and I have managers for doing some actions with different resources. I would like to check for example, that each method of different methods return 200 as response code. So I inherit my tests from similar base and use fixtures to do different actions.

Comment: It's quite unidiomatic for pytest testsuites to use inheritance, and indeed it causes issues with markers "smearing" - a better mechanism would be to define fixtures in a [`conftest.py` file](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#sharing-a-fixture-across-tests-in-a-module-or-class-session) and use normal functions for the tests.

Comment: You can take a look at my example here: https://github.com/grundic/yagocd/blob/master/tests/__init__.py: this file has  basic implementation of different tests and raises `NotImplementedError` for fixtures that I expect to provide in child classes. So right now I've just override method in required classes, running `super`: https://github.com/grundic/yagocd/blob/master/tests/test_pipeline_manager.py#L416